# Vuejs api response result to many variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue to make http request and fetch data into variables like this:
my api response looks like this:

```
data:
   data: [id:1... etc]
```

function:

```
    fetchOffers() {
        this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offers')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => this.offers = result.data)

    },
```

all works fine,

Now I used Laravel resource so my response looks like this:

```
data:
   data: [id:1... etc]
   links: [...]
   meta: [...]
```

so I want to get those properties into other variables, but unfortunately it doesn't work and only the first variable is set, the other two are empty:

```
    fetchOffers() {
        this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offers')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => this.pagination = result.meta)
            .then(result => this.links = result.links)
            .then(result => this.offers = result.data)
    },
```

anyone has an idea why this is not working? Should I write it other way?

Answer (score 2):

set the variables on the last promise, so it will be like

```
fetchOffers() {
    this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/offers')
        .then(response => response.json()) // this will return a Promise
        .then(result => { 
                    this.pagination = result.meta
                    this.links = result.links
                    this.offers = result.data
        })
},
```